# how to select dates dynamically between 2 dates

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, date, selenium

I am writing tests for flights. I need to select dates between 30th march 2011 to 30th april 2011. for departure and return flights. Any idea how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
    Dim days As Integer = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, startdate, enddate)
    Dim newDate As Date = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, (New Random).Next(0, days), startdate)
```

Comment: I think the OP is trying to figure out how to use Selenium to automate the selection of dates in a calendar GUI.